# Carriage return and line feed not being replaced into VBA string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing some logs entries into a csv file however when I'm trying to replace CR and LF into a specific string I'm getting the same result as before.

```
Replace(SQLStatement, vbTab & Chr$(13) & Chr$(10), "")
```

Not being able to remove CR and LF, and even Tabs, is affecting my csv and finally in the Excel file the string is outputed on more lines instead of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will only replace the specific combination of `vbTab & Chr$(13) & Chr$(10)`.

If you want to replace them you will need to do the individually.

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(SQLStatement, vbTab,""), Chr$(13),""), Chr$(10), "")
```

Although you need to be careful that your lines do not run into one another.  You might be safer with

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(SQLStatement, vbTab," "), Chr$(13)," "), Chr$(10), " ")
```